# Archive format that can be unpacked without copying its content?

Tags: zip, archive, 7zip

Main question: if you want bundle multiple files or an entire directory structure (without compression), formats like .tar or .zip can be used. However when unpacking those archives, all its contents need to be copied. Is there an archive format that can be unpacked 'in place', i.e. without copying its contents?

Motivation: I need to send directories containing tens of GB of compressed video data from one computer to another (relatively small number of big files). Specifically: I am responsible for packing and unpacking the data on both ends, but another business partner is responsible for the actual transport (it happens on their machines).
Asking a business partner to move single files simplifies things from a business standpoint a lot. The questions 'did something go wrong?' and 'show something went wrong to possibly technically inexperienced managers' is a lot simpler with a single file than with a directory structure of many files.
The obvious choice here is to just zip/unzip it using 7zip. However on the unpacking side, this requires unpacking GB of data. Worse: since these are uncompressed zip-files, the unpacking mainly consists of copying GB of video data that was already exactly where it needed to be, only inside an archive.
So a lot of time is spent on basically unnecessary work. This makes me wonder: is there an archive format that does something like 'pretend this directory structure is a single file' and then gives the option to say 'now stop pretending this directory structure is a single file'. I imagine this would require something like unindexing and then reindexing the individual files, but since there are relatively few files, I would imagine this would be a lot faster than copying everything.

Does anyone know an archive format that could help me here?

Comment: One part of creating an archive is that it will treat that whole directory as one File. So as you can't just get to access some part of the file if you don't open it, or in this case you decompress it.

Comment: Thats true, decompressing it will always require opening the file. My question is whether decompressing always requires copying/reading the entire file. Suppose you would register that the first 10GB of the file is 'video1.avi' and the second 10GB is 'video2.avi'. Could you just relabel this data as individual files without copying all 20GB of it?

Comment: You can verify that the zip file came across correctly by running "unzip -t zipfile.zip". To achieve this the zip file needs to be uncompressed, but it won't be written to disk - the whole operation is done in memory. The reason for this is the checksums used by zip are  for the uncompressed content.